# How To Keep Original Key on Array Merge

Tags: php, array-merge

I have two dynamic associated array and I am trying to merge them into one array BUT I need to keep the original `keys` as the orginal arrays but in return I am getting `[0]` for `A` which I need to keep it `[1]` as it was in array `$a`

```
$a = ["1"=>"A", "2"=>"B", "3"=>"C"];
$b = ["n"=>"5"];
$c = array_merge($a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

> Array (
>              [0] => A
>              [1] => B
>              [2] => C
>              [n] => 5 
> )

Comment: i am not a php developer. but have you tried to do it like the php documentation at http://php.net/array_merge? the declareit with $a = array(... ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to preserve keys of your array you need to use `+` operator over here like as

```
$a = ["1"=>"A", "2"=>"B", "3"=>"C"];
$b = ["n"=>"5"];
$c = $a + $b;
print_r($c);
```

You can check PHP Manuals [**Example #2 Simple array_merge() example**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

> i am not a php developer. so there could be better answers out there

the php documentation says that numerical keys are new numbered. i think that even a string as key with a nummeric value is interpretet as number.

can you try this (not the added 'a' on the nummeric keys):

```
$a = ["1a"=>"A", "2a"=>"B", "3a"=>"C"];
$b = ["n"=>"5"];
$c = array_merge($a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

it is not clean code, but after this you can "remove" the 'a' and you have your  numeric key